# Android service is executing twice

Tags: android, service, handler

I'm making an android app.
I'm starting a service in my launch activity by calling method startService in onCreate Method in main Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    starService();
}


 private void starService() {
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), HelenaService.class));
 }
```

when i do a toast to see how the methods are called in my service. I see that this method is called twice..

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I mean, i can see the first toast immediately called and after a few seconds the exact same toast message appears.

How can I make sure the onStart method is called only once.  Tried a flag, but the variables are restarted.

Any help? or advices?

Comment: Can you post more of the service? Also, where are you calling startService()?

Comment: I'm calling starService()  in onCreate method of launcher activity.   The service only has toast msg in the methods : onStartCommand and OnStart

Comment: Check my answer and see if it is accurate.

Comment: you mean I see twice the Toast msg, because i put two Toast msgs in both methods?   I did, but each toast has a diferent msg,  "toast in start" and "toast in startCommand", and I see both of this two times in a few seconds..

Comment: Ahh, see these are details that need to be provided initially. Did you do the Log.e? What happens?

Comment: Did my answer resolve your issue? If so can you accept.

Answer (score 0):

The flag variables are being "restarted" because you are starting a new service in starService()

Without seeing more of your code a solution I can see would be to put a flag within starService()

```
private Boolean flag = true;
```

then:

```
private void starService() {
 if (flag){
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), HelenaService.class));
    flag = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: tryied, I still can see the service is executing twice.

Comment: You need to post your code there is no way to tell from the snippets you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
String TAG = CLASSNAME.class.getConicalName();
```

Place a `Log.e(TAG, "---onStart()---");` and `Log.e(TAG, "---onStartCommand()---");` inside the respective methods.

Check the LogCat under "error" and if you see both these logs, than both methods are being called.

If both of these methods are called when the service starts, and they both contain a toast, than that is the reason you are seeing the toast twice.

Also, you may want to force stop/clear data inside the application settings in the event the service continue to run after you close the application. You will want to implement logic to stop the service such as stopSelf();